# What is your way of cleaning up image resources in a project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unmanagedresources

I'm doing a huge cleanup in my project, getting rid of old image resources. The way i do it is to go through every resource and search the code for a match on the resource name.
how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be quite helpful:  [Tool for finding unused images within an excode project](http://maniacdev.com/2013/01/tool-for-finding-unused-images-within-an-xcode-project-to-help-reduce-app-bundle-size)